# How can i embed an image to csv or excel using php

Tags: php, excel, csv

i create a csv using  fopen and trying to put html content  with an image to this csv using fwrite.

Anyway its not working !!!!

How can i embed an image to csv/excel   using PHP .?

Comment: Are you sure you want to be using a csv for this purpose?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I don't think embedding an image into a CSV file is a viable option. If you are trying to create an Excel file with images then you can try out a library called [PHPExcel](http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/).

Comment: +1 for PHPExcel, which does allow images to be embedded in Excel files

Comment: @Mark - I was expecting an answer from Mark :-) as i put "excel" in my question. Php excel credit goes to him . http://phpexcel.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Credits&referringTitle=Features

Comment: @zod - I was a bit slow in answering, and Abhinav got in first, but it's the answer I'd have given and he deserves the upvotes/acceptance for it. There's a couple of examples of embedding an image in the sample scripts in the /Tests directory of the PHPExcel distribution that demonstrate how to do what you ask